# How to add ImplicitlyAnimatedReorderableList (Reordareble ) in ExpansionPanelList?

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, flutter-layout, flutter-engine

I'm Using  **ImplicitlyAnimatedReorderableList** (implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: ^0.2.3) : https://pub.dev/packages/implicitly_animated_reorderable_list

Facing issue :

[image: ImplicitlyAnimatedReorderableList in ExpansionPanelList]

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#ea59f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1713 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```